# Convert multiline string in a variable in bash to a single-line string with newlines escaped

Tags: bash

I am looking for a way to convert a multiline string in a variable in bash to a single-line string that has each `\n` character escaped as the `\n` literal.

For example:

```
str="
Hello
World
"
```

I need this to become `Hello\nWorld`. I looked through the questions on SO and Unix StackExchange but I haven't been able to find a command yet that achieves what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bash has two built-in ways to quote values suitable for re-ingestion. These will handle not only newlines but also tabs, quotes, and backslashes:

```
❯ echo "${str@Q}"
$'\nHello\nWorld\n'
```

```
❯ printf '%q\n' "$str"
$'\nHello\nWorld\n'
```

Alternatively, if you simply want to replace newlines and nothing else you can use `${var//search/replace}` syntax to do replacements:

```
❯ echo "${str//$'\n'/\\n}"
\nHello\nWorld\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed -zn 's/\n/\\n/p' <<< "$str"
```

Use -z to consume the variable as one line and substitute new lines for literal newlines.